# Can't resolve all parameters for - Angular dependency injection

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, primeng

So I created a wrapper around PrimeNg's MessageService and injected it into my components. The code works, the messages are showing and all, but VSCode marks my component class with a red underline and says:

> Can't resolve all parameters for ProductListComponent in
> .../read/product-list.component.ts: ([object Object], [object Object],
> ?, [object Object], [object Object]).ng

This is my component class:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'product-list.component.html'
})
export class ProductListComponent {

    constructor(
        private breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService,
        productService: Productservice,
        private messageServiceWrapper: MessageServiceWrapper,
        private confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
        private translate: TranslateService
    ) {}
}
```

This is the service that Angular cannot inject:

```
import { MessageService } from 'primeng';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export default class MessageServiceWrapper {
    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
        this.clearMessages();
    }

    showErrorMessage(summary: string, detail: string): void {
        this.clearMessages();
        this.messageService.add({ key: 'local', severity: 'error', summary, detail });
    }

    showInfoMessage(summary: string, detail: string): void {
        this.clearMessages();
        this.messageService.add({ key: 'local', severity: 'info', summary, detail });
    }

    clearMessages(): void {
        this.messageService.clear();
    }

    showSuccessMessage(summary: string): void {
        this.clearMessages();
        this.messageService.add({ key: 'local', severity: 'success', summary });
    }
}
```

The component's module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
        ProductListComponent,
        ...
    ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        CommonModule,
        MessagesModule,
        MessageModule,
        CardModule,
        InputSwitchModule,
        ConfirmDialogModule,
        InputTextModule,
        DialogModule,
        AutoCompleteModule,
        ToastModule,
        FileUploadModule,
        PaginatorModule,
        ButtonModule,
        TranslateModule,
        AppTableModule,
        ProductRoutingModule,
    ],
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

I tried declaring the service in a shared module but that didn't help either.

Comment: try to remove "default" from You "export default class MessageServiceWrapper", leaf export class MessageServiceWrapper

Comment: @TomaszVizaint that actually worked! but why?

Comment: Exactly today I have the same problem, deleting the default looks like an open file for injection, don't know why

Comment: that is because AOT compiler does not expect that way of exporting services, and, as it should create correct metadata it misses the class that is exported as defeault

Comment: Try changing the line `productService: Productservice` to `private productService: Productservice`